# Why does Perl replace my string with "1"?

Tags: regex, perl, string, replace

I have the following code:

```
#$domain = domainname.co.uk
#$root = public_html
#$webpage = domainname.co.uk/foo/bar/foobar.html
my $string = ($webpage =~ s/^$domain//g);
my $linkFromRoot = $dbh->quote($root . $string);
```

Usualy this works fine but for some reason the output is "public_html 1" instead of "public_html/foo/bar/foobar.html".

Can anyone see why?

Comment: When you run into these problems, start bisecting your code to find where the problem data shows up. In this case, you'd check the value of `$string` before you use it, find out that it's `1`, then read up on the substitution operator to see what it's doing. :)

Comment: Off-topic again, but why DBI `quote` instead of placeholders? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not getting the correct answer because the substitution returns you 1 which is the number of items substituted. See [perlfaq4](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html)'s answer to [How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_can_I_count_the_)

```
$domain = "domainname.co.uk";
$root = "public_html";
$webpage = "domainname.co.uk/foo/bar/foobar.html";
my $string = ($webpage =~ s/^$domain//g);
print $string."\n";
```

Remove the `$string` and just do `$webpage =~ s/^$domain//g;` and then do the string concatenation with `$webpage`.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are assuming that the parentheses around the regular expression induce a list context on it. That it **not** the case. The left of the assignment operator determines the context, and it is scalar. In scalar context, s/// returns the number of successful substitutions. Putting parentheses around the declared variable variable makes it do what you want it to do, because it makes for a list context.

This:

```
my ($string) = $webpage =~ s/^$domain//;
```

Would return the matches part of $webpage: the domain name. This is probably not what you want. You either want S.Mark's code:

```
$webpage =~ s/^$domain//;
my $linkFromRoot = $dbh->quote($root . $webpage);
```

Or this

```
my ($string) = $webpage =~ /^$domain(.+)$//;
my $linkFromRoot = $dbh->quote($root . $string);
```

Comment: I like that you explained the possible mistake in understanding context.  It's too important a topic in Perl to miss a chance to reinforce it.

Answer (score 4):

Completely off the topic of your original question, but is it possible that what you actually wanted was:

```
my $webpage = URI->new("http://domainname.co.uk/foo/bar.html");
my $path = $webpage->rel("http://domainname.co.uk/");
print "public_html/$path\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$webpage =~ s/^$domain//g;
my $linkFromRoot = $dbh->quote($root . $webpage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need another variable, I think the answers above are better, but one of my favorite little syntax tricks is to take advantage of the fact that assignment is an lvalue, so with a little rearrangement of the parenthesis:

```
(my $string = $webpage) =~ s/^$domain//g;
```

you can make a copy and modify it in one statement.

Also, along with the other stuff that's a bit weird about this code, there's not much point to that `/g` on a pattern starting with `^`.  It can't match more than once.